# Different solution from textbook regarding exact ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm currently using the textbook *Advanced Engineering Mathematics 10e (Kreyszig, 2019)* and had a question regarding one of the example problems for exact ordinary differential equations.

Here's the question:

> Solve the initial value problem:
>
> $$(\cos{y}\sinh{x} + 1)dx - \sin{y}\cosh{x}dy = 0$$
>
> $$y(1) = 2$$

I followed the textbook approach by following the steps provided for solving exact ODE's, but am getting a different result and one part of the solution is confusing me.

**My approach**

$$
\begin{align}
M(x, y) & = \cos(y)\sinh(x) + 1 \\
N(x, y) & = \sin(y)\cosh(x)
\end{align}
$$

$$\partial M / \partial y = \partial N / \partial x$$

$$
\begin{align}
u & = \int (\cos(y)\sinh(x) + 1 )dx + k(y) \\
& = \cos(y)\cosh(x) + k(y) \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} & = -\sin(y)\cosh(x) + k'(y) \\
& = N(x, y)
\end{align}
$$

After solving the last part, it can be shown that $k'(y) = 0$ and so I wrote $k(y) = C$. However, the solution states that $k(y) = x + C$. I understand that this also makes sense, but how should I know when to put the $x$ there and when not?

Comment: $k'(y) = 0$ means $k$'s derivative w.r.t. $y$ as a function of $y$. Does not say anything about how $k$ would vary w.r.t. $x$. Due to linearity of ODE:s any additive function of $x$ could potentially do. Maybe a little more investigation is needed to determine that exactly $x$ is this function of x that will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral in your solution has a $+1$ which you ignored to integrate . That is why you lost the $x$ in your answer.

Comment: Don't know why I completely missed that. Thank you for pointing it out.